# how to stack numpy array in a list

Tags: python

Say I have 3 numpy arrays: array([1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]) and array([1, 2, 3, 4])

I want to get a list that look like [array([1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])]

This can be done directly. However, I wonder how to get it done iteratively. Because if I start with L=[] and do

```
for i in range(3,6):
    L=[L, np.array(range(1,i))]
```

Then finally I will get a list of lists: [[[[], array([1, 2])], array([1, 2, 3])], array([1, 2, 3, 4])]. How can I get the desired result? Thanks.

The np.array(range(1,i)) is just an example. It can be any 1-D numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = []
for i in range(3,6):
    L.append(np.array(range(1,i)))
```

The creates:

```
[array([1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

Alternatively, because `L` is a python list and not a numpy array:

```
L = []
for i in range(3,6):
    L = L + [np.array(range(1,i))]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will work if you use `append` or `+=`, but you can also do this easily with the list comprehension:

```
[np.arange(1, i) for i in range(3,6)]
```